# ClientInterceptor - capturing 404 scenarios

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using **ClientInterceptor** to intercept all the external soap calls made by my application and log the request and response. I am able to capture the request / response and fault scenarios. However when I see a 404 error due to endpoint being incorrectly configured , I am unable to capture this using the methods provided by this interface. Is there a way to capture 404 error using this interface? If not , can you please help in letting me know the alternative that I need to explore?

> org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor.handleFault()` only suits for intercepting the processes of incoming response fault. That is the SOAP faults defined by specification. So the [SOAP 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383529) and [1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-soap12-part2-20020626/#tabreqstatereqtrans) specifications define a status codes which are returned in case of SOAP fauls (for example in case of malformed XML in the request message envelope). SOAP 1.1 specifies a 500 status code for faults and SOAP 1.2 specifies a 400 status code for sender faults, and 500 for all other faults. In case of faults the server returns SOAP message in the response containing a SOAP Fault element which then can be passed to the `ClientInterceptor.handleFault()` methods. But 404 status code indicates that it is not a SOAP failure but system error. So if you need to handle that case as well you need to overwrite the `WebServiceTemplate.handleError()` method instead.

This will do the trick

```
public class CustomWebServiceTemplate extends WebServiceTemplate{

    @Override
    protected Object handleError(WebServiceConnection connection, WebServiceMessage request) throws IOException {
        log.info("Log the error case in here");
        return super.handleError(connection, request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Babl. Is there a way to get MessageContext object within handleError method?

Comment: I have set some properties in messagecontext as part of handleRequest method. If I need to handle the timeout response using handleError method , is there a way for me to access the elements in messagecontext?

Comment: No easy way, I mean nothing is impossible but you will need to overwrite the `WebServiceTemplate .doSendAndReceive` to have fully custom things ... The problem with the default implementation is the fact that it only sends the request to the `handleError` method like `handleError(connection, messageContext.getRequest());`. So if you really need it you need to play a bit with `WebServiceTemplate .doSendAndReceive`

Comment: Hey @Babl , just an update - I was able to intercept these messages in after complete method in the class that extends clientinterceptor.  Thank you.